# how do I get my mustache.js template file included?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mustache

I'm working with mustache.js for the first time. All the examples I'm finding seem to talk about putting everything inline, but I want my templates in external files so they can be used in multiple places. How do I do that? (I've got jQuery in my stack, if that makes a difference.)

So say I have:

template.html

```
{{title}} spends {{calc}}
```

data.js

```
var data = { title: "Joe", calc: function() { return 2 + 4; } };
```

index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="data.js"></script>

<div id="target"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var template = ?????? // how do I attach the template?
    var html = Mustache().to_html(template, data);
    $('#target')[0].innerHTML = html;
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template = $('.template').val();
```

Where your template is in the DOM...

```
<textarea class="template"> 
<h1>{{header}}</h1>
{{#bug}}
{{/bug}}

{{#items}}
  {{#first}}
    <li><strong>{{name}}</strong></li>
  {{/first}}
  {{#link}}
    <li><a href="{{url}}">{{name}}</a></li>
  {{/link}}
{{/items}}

{{#empty}}
  <p>The list is empty.</p>
{{/empty}}
</textarea>
```

You could also render multiple templates directly into your page...

```
<script id="yourTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl"> 
    {{tmpl "#yourTemplate"}}
    <div>Something: ${TemplateValue}</div>
</script>
```

Comment: Oh, if your entire page was the template you could probably use $('body').val();

Comment: But the template is in an external file! that's the whole point. I guess I could make an ajax call to get it, but I'm wondering if there's a better way....

Comment: Ah ok, yep, I'd AJAX out to get it and onSuccess assign the response to the template var.

Comment: It will probably give solutions for server-side compiled scripts. Hogan.JS mentions something like this: http://twitter.github.com/hogan.js/